# Fastest Way to Update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a Vb.net application that is updating a table in a SQL Server database very frequently. The table has 143 columns and about 10,000 rows. The same procedure is required to update the table for several different modules so the data updated is different all the time, sometimes it could be just a few cells in a few rows other times it may be several hundred rows and several columns.

At times it's taking 15 to 30 seconds to update the information. That seams really long given that the table can be totally re-written with a bulk import in a second or 2 (I realise that that is beside the point). The database is set to simple recovery, the table has only one index. I have tried playing around with the update batch size to no noticeable improvement.

I'm using the below code to do the update. Is there anything that I can do to improve the speed?

```
 Dim oMainQueryR As String

    If DBSelectionsDS.HasChanges Then

        Try
                oMainQueryR = "SELECT * FROM DBSelections"

                Using connection As New SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
                    Using oDataSQL As New SqlDataAdapter(oMainQueryR, connection)
                        oDataSQL.UpdateBatchSize = 100
                        Using cbT As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(oDataSQL)
                            connection.Open()
                            oDataSQL.Update(DBSelectionsDS, "DBSelectionsDetails")
                            connection.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using


                DBSelectionsDS.Tables("DBSelectionsDetails").AcceptChanges()

        Catch ex As Exception

            ErrMess = "ERROR - occured  " & ex.ToString
            Call WriteError()
            Call ViewError()

        End Try

    End If
```

Comment: How many rows do we talk per update?

Comment: could be anywhere from 1 to about a 1000, but that is about the limit of the rows that need updating

Comment: should add that not all columns change at the same time, it may be 1000 rows with info changed in 2 columns (cells per row), it usually isn't more then 2-5 columns (cells) per row being changed. However as I explained there are many functions that use the same update module so its impossible to know which cells have changed each time the update is called. Probably in hindsight it could have been better written, but Im stuck with what I have

Comment: Have you got any triggers on this table? Also did you try running an Sql Server Profiler session to see exactly what is being sent to the server?

Comment: What about changing the code, rather then having the adapter handle the process what about using getchanges method on the table to get a datatable of only the changes and then specifically type out the update statement and send it as a transaction. I did something similar on SQLite query and the update speed difference was staggering, although its more intensive as the update statement has to be hardcoded with every row and every parameter. Would that work in MS SQL? I have never used a transaction in MS SQL before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be willing to bet the bottleneck lies in two places:

First, You are selecting *everything* from your table *every time* you need to run the update.  This will take longer and longer as your table grows in size.  The `SqlCommandBuilder` only needs a schema to work with so change your query string to this:

```
oMainQueryR = "SELECT * FROM DBSelections WHERE 0 = 1"
```

This will return only the schema and column names for the table but no rows, your `DataSet` contains all the data information the `CommandBuilder` needs to perform the update.  If you are curious why this works, consider that 0 will never equal 1, so SQL says there are *never* any rows where 0 = 1, and just returns the schema instead.

Second, the `UpdateBatchSize` is limiting the batch size of the update. 
    Consider having 200 rows of changed data in your `DataSet`.  You
    will then have to take 2 trips to the database to finish the update.
    Setting `UpdateBatchSize = 0` will remove this limit, also you can
    just remove the line as the default is 0.

Otherwise your bottleneck *could* be caused by another transaction locking the `DBSelections` table. Ensure that if you are running any queries against that table while the update is happening, you will either want to use the `with (nolock)` statement, or ensure that your update is the only transaction occurring at the time.

Comment: I was under the impression the command builder was clever enough to fetch the schema only out of the query.

Comment: If you think about it, the command *has* to go to SQL in order to get the schema, so even if the command builder doesn't actually *use* any of the data present.  The SQL Server still has to process the command exactly as it was received.

Comment: Not necessarily. Read about command behavior `SchemaOnly`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.100)

Comment: @Crono Interesting!  Well... I'm always open to learning something new!  Thanks!  I still think that in the current context of the OP's code, he either needs to employ the use of `SchemaOnly` or use the `where 0 = 1` trick to avoid getting all rows.  `SchemaOnly` would certainly be cleaner.

Comment: the select command initially mad difference by changing the update time from 15 sec to about 3 sec. But when I restarted the PC and re run it it was again back to 15 sec even with that statement , when I ran the procedure a few times all of a sudden the update time again went to 3 sec. Is that some sort of SQL adaptive algorithm ? I was excited by 3 sec at least for a while.

Comment: The batch size didn't make any difference either, and I know there is no other transaction locking the database as this is a single thread, single user local operation. However I do appreciate your time taken to help me , thank you

Comment: @user1500403 The only other thing I could think of would be CPU/Memory load differences at the time of the update.  If the DB is running on your local machine, maybe monitor system processes at the time of the update.  SQL can be fairly memory intensive.  Otherwise, besides differences in the update size, there are too many other factors to consider to be sure about anything.